# Setting input range slider max attribute with js on howler.js project

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, slider, howler.js

I have an audio player I'm making using howler.js
I am setting the input range slider max attribute dynamically using J query.

I'm able to set the max to match the audio.duration().

Example: If audio source is 177.777 seconds, I set the max attribute to that. I can see using dev inspector that the max attribute changes.

Thats great, but.

The problem is when I change the max attribute , the slider doesn't reflect it.

The slider only reflects whatever the original hardcoded max="100" is.

So if i move the slider and the audio is for instance 177.777 seconds long, the slider ends before the audio, in other words the duration of the audio won't fit or vice versa, if I set the max="1000" , the slider only reaches 10% before the audio ends.

The slider css width is set to 100%, thats not the problem.

I'm not sure if its the way howler.js instantiates the howler sound object, or if its something else, do i need to maybe also reset the input range value attribute? any help is welcome.

below are some code examples:

HTML: `<input id="song1" class="songSlider" type="range" value="0" min="0" step="1" max="1000">`

JS:

```
sound[soundid] = new Howl({
      src: ['../audio/' + musicIdentifier],
      volume: 0.8,
      onload: function() {
      $('input[type=range]').attr('max', sound[soundid].duration());


      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, hope this helps someone with the same problem.

I had to get the range slider current value, then divide it by my current max attribute, then multiply that by the audio.duration:

example:

```
var $max = $('input[type=range]').attr('max');
$songCurrentTime = $(".songSlider").val();
$newCurentTmeValue = ($songCurrentTime / $max) * currentAudioPlaying.duration();
```